# parsing json array in label swift 4

Tags: json, parsing, uilabel, swift4.2

This is my JSON array

```
[  
   {  
      "dollar":"15000",
      "date":"1397-12-12"
   }
]
```

i want to show dollar and date values in two different label but i have this type mismatch  error :

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

this is my Struct :

```
    struct Dollar_Date : Codable {
    let dollar : String
    let date : String
}
```

and this is my code in view controller :

```
func dollarLabel() {

let urlString = DOLLAR_DATE_BASE_URL
guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

// 2
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
    }

    guard let data = data else { return }
    do {
        // 3
        //Decode data
        let JSONData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Dollar_Date.self, from: data)

        // 4
        print(JSONData.dollar)
        //Get back to the main queue
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.main_Price.text = JSONData.dollar
            self.data_Label.text = JSONData.date
        }

    } catch let jsonError {
        print(jsonError)
    }
    // 5
    }.resume()
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
guard let jsonArray = JSONData as? [[String: Any]] else {
      return 
}
print(jsonArray)
//Now get title value 
guard let title = jsonArray[0]["title"] as? String else { return } print(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because your data contains an array of JSON (dictionary as well), not JSON itself.

So you can't decode with

```
 let JSONData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Dollar_Date.self, from: data)
```

But you have to do it manually:

***EDIT:***

```
guard let json = data as? [[String:Any]] else{return}
```

Now you can retrieve dollars and date from all the elements of your array:

```
 // These are because you have to access an element of the array
 guard let dollar = json[0]["dollar"] as? String else {return}
 guard let date = json[0]["date"] as? String else {return}

 DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.main_Price.text = dollar
        self.data_Label.text = date
    }
```

if your data can contain multiple value (dollars-date couples) you have to loop your array. By the previous example, you should do:

```
for element in json{
    guard let dollar = element["dollar"] as? String else {return}
    guard let date = element["date"] as? String else {return}

    // do some stuff with each value
}
```

Comment: tnx i have this alert : Cast from 'Dollar_Date' to unrelated type '[[String : Any]]' always fails in this line : guard let json = JSONData as? [[String:Any]] else{return} and type mismatch exist yet

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the variables. Check the edit, you have to use data instead of JSONData